# forecast and fable return different outputs on same dataset for forecasting in R

Tags: r, forecasting, fable-r

I am trying to understand the different between two forecasting package `forecast` and `fable`, as the two editions of the same book ([second edition](https://otexts.com/fpp2/holt.html) and [third edition](https://otexts.com/fpp3/holt.html) seems to imply that the two packages are equivalent.

```
library(dplyr)

raw <- c(44.4082519001086, 47.1074380165289, 43.5633367662204, 43.1003584229391, 
         42.5828970331588, 38.3217993079585, 38.5751520417029)
# raw <- c(raw,rev(raw))

forecast.df <- ts(raw)
forecast::autoplot(forecast.df) +
  forecast::autolayer(forecast::holt(forecast.df,damped=FALSE,h = 5),
                      series="Holt's method",PI = TRUE)


fable.df <- tsibble::as_tsibble(tibble(value=raw) %>%
                                 mutate(time=1:n()),index=time)
fable.df %>%
  fabletools::model(`Holt's method`=
                      fable::ETS(value ~ error("A") + trend("A") + season("N"))) %>%
  fabletools::forecast(.,h=5) %>%
  fabletools::autoplot(fable.df,level=c(80,95))
```

By eyeballing the two charts, the boundaries of prediction interval generated by `fabletools` are parallel, compared with those generated by `forecast` being in funnel shape.

I am not sure if I have missed some parameters when setting up `forecast` or `fable`. Thanks!